# How to export time duration data in a "37:30:55" format in R?

Tags: r, time-format

I have a data frame in R which has values like `1900-01-01 21:00:00` indicating 45 hrs of time duration. I am using **fwrite** function to export the data-frame in a csv format and desire to get the output as `45:00:00`. Defining the format as `"%H:%M"` for the corresponding column using **format** function only results in truncation of data and the exported csv shows up `21:00:00`, so it's not working out.

Is there a R equivalent of MS Excel's time format `"37:30:55"` ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a package *that implements the 'duration' aspect* of date and time calculus.

Here is an example from the [nanotime](https://cloud.r-project.org/package=nanotime) package I am a co-author of:

```
> library(nanotime)
> nd <- as.nanoduration("37:30:55")
> nd
[1] 37:30:55
> Sys.time() 
[1] "2021-07-24 12:57:05.645062 CDT"
> as.nanotime(Sys.time()) + nd
[1] 2021-07-26T07:28:11.613602+00:00
>
```

(I may be using the GitHub rather than CRAN version here; I am a little behind making a release but plan to do so 'real soon now'.)  The 'lubridate' package likely has related functionality, as does my (old) package 'RcppBDT' wrapping Boost Date_Time.